# is there any thing like get_next in redis?

Tags: redis

Is there any support in redis to walk keys ? some thing like get_next api  ? I did some search but couldnt find any thing relevant. my requirement is to get a key from a value so i iterate over all the keys and try to match the value with that of the required.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, there's no get_next type of api/command in Redis. You can do some trick with the key though. Something like `1:id:<key_name>, 2:id:<key_name>, ..., n:id:<key_name>`. You can use [INCR](http://redis.io/commands/incr) to have an incremental counter. Also consider looking at [keys](http://redis.io/commands/keys) to find a bunch of keys with a particular pattern.

Comment: Thank you very much keys command was what i was looking for my keys are all follow some pattern.

Comment: KEYS does a linear scan over all keys, so avoid it if you have a large number of databases. Recall, too, that Redis is single threaded, so as the KEYS command runs, all other commands will be blocked.